# Error in query syntax

Tags: php, mysql

i am using ORDER BY in mysql SELECT query but i dont know ots not ordering the data.. if i use this query its showing the table but not ordering the data in ascending order

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY 'order' ASC")or   die(mysql_error());
```

but if i use

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY order ASC")or die(mysql_error());
```

then it give error that the syntax of the query is not right...i've seen on various sites but i couldnot found anything unique in my code...i think its right,...please check the query and mend a solution. Thankx in advance :)

Comment: As everyone are saying, change order to some other name.  It is a reserved word

Comment: Keep in mind that the table may _not_ be under the control of the person querying it. Yes, it's a good idea to use column names that aren't reserved but not if it's going to involve a 3-week fight with the DBAs, or changes to 42 other programs that already query the `order` column.

Comment: @paxdiablo good point, But, If the DBA or anyother person is using keywords for naming columns i will fight for whole life

Comment: Mess not with DBAs because they're sensitive and quick to anger :-) And do you really want to anger someone who can hurt you with a `drop table` incantation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *backticks,* not single quotes <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
... SELECT * FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY `order` ASC ...
```

By using single quotes, you're ordering the rows by a *constant* (each row gets the same constant) so effectively not ordering them at all.

By using a "naked" column name of `order`, you're confusing the SQL parser, since `order` is a reserved word.

---

<sup>(a):</sup> Of course, this problem goes away if you stop using reserved words as column names but I assume you did that for a reason (such as a bucket-load of programs *already* depending on the fact that the column is called `order`).

Myself, I tend not to use generic names for columns (such as `order` or `date`), preferring instead things that don't conflict with the language (such as `order_num` or `start_date`). That way I don't have to worry about escaping.

Comment: backticks: `"SELECT * FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY \`order\` ASC"`; also "mot" => "not"

Comment: Also it might be a good idea not to use reserved words as column names.

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQL reserved keyword `order` as a column name so use back-ticks to escape...like this

```
SELECT * FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

**I would suggest you to change the columnn name**

Reference For List Of [Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: anyone please tell me y im getting negative points for this question.. i knw im not a good coder.. but im a beginner..please tell me how can i get upvotes on this question, thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER` is a reserved sql syntax keyword. you cannot use it directly

```
SELECT *FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY `order` ASC
-------------------------------^---------
```

in second case

```
SELECT *FROM learningmaterial ORDER BY order ASC
---------------------------------^-------^--
//this is a sql error
```

it doesn't  make any sense.

Comment: In what sense it doesn't make any sense? it does make sense, it's just the back ticks he is missing

Comment: @Mr.Alien: "*in second case ... it doesn't make any sense*".

Comment: @eggyal but the query does make sense

Comment: @Mr.Alien it is visible to everyone that OP is missing back-ticks.but i want to show how it doesn't make sense in query

Comment: @jhonraymos ok..cool.. just saw you've lil arrows below that ;)

Comment: anyone please tell me y im getting negative points for this question.. i knw im not a good coder.. but im a beginner..please tell me how can i get upvotes on this question, thanx :)

Comment: @troublecreator what is your database schema..?

Comment: @jhonraymos 
 i didnt get u, i am i dont have any issues with the query now..i just want to ask y i got down votes on this question...please tell me how would i get upvotes on this question??? :(

Answer (score 1):

Since `Order` is a reserved word, you need to wrap them using backticks not single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM `learningmaterial` ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Comment: Aren't you just repeating what all the earlier answers said?

Comment: Thaaanxxx Awlll..... im just a beginner..but i should know these things..i dont know it just slipped out of my mind... any ways thnx alot :)

Comment: anyone please tell me y im getting negative points for this question.. i knw im not a good coder.. but im a beginner..please tell me how can i get upvotes on this question, thanx :)